# What are the sources for עין הרע?

Tags: sources-mekorot, ayin-hara-evil-eye

What are the sources for עין הרע?
Where does it say practical advice for when you feel you might be effected by עין הרע and you want to take action?

Comment: Generally speaking, Rb Dessler seems to understand *ayin ha'ra* is a *kitrug* which is *me'orrer the middas ha'din*. The *mekubalim* seem to have a more basic understanding of *ayin ha'ra* wherein *ayin ha'ra* is an "evil force" or "damaging agent" that comes from a jealous look. The most basic defence to *ayin ha'ra* is not to show off or to hide your success. (The *mekubalim* seem to have a different approach to this, however.) If you feel you have been affected by *ayin ha'ra*, hide the success that caused the *ayin ha'ra*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an intro, a little story from Rabbi Nachman's Tales #9, the Sophisticate and the Simpleton:

> When he (the Simpleton) would finish a shoe — and the shoe probably had three corners [i.e., it was not symmetrical] since he did not have complete proficiency in his craft — he would take the shoe in his hand and praise it highly. And he would take great pleasure from it and would say, "My wife, how beautiful and wonderful is this shoe! How sweet it is! What a honey, what a sugary shoe this is!" She would ask him, "If that is so, why do other shoemakers take three gulden for a pair of shoes, and you take only a half thaler (one and a half gulden)?" He replied, "What's that to me? That's the other person's business and this is my business. And besides, why do we have to talk about other people? Let's just start calculating how much I earn with this shoe "from hand to hand" [from his hand to the hand of the customer--i.e., considering all factors in the process of making and selling the shoe]. The leather costs me this much, tar and thread cost this much, the filling between the skins this much, and likewise other items this much; comes out that I profit ten groschen from hand to hand. And with such a profit from hand to hand, what is there to be concerned about?"
>
> So he was only happy and cheerful at all times, but to the world he was a laughingstock...

So the basic advice to avoid Ayin haRa (jealousy, tightfistedness) whether as the object or agent, seems to be:

- Don't look (the eye sees, then the heart desires..)
- Don't compare (versus others)
- Don't count (where there's no quantifying then Ayin haRa is powerless)

That is, to mind one's own business and be happy in his lot, without comparing or quantifying in comparison to others.

As for sources perhaps the earliest source is Kain and Havel (Gen. 4)?

Some others:

Rabbeinu Yonah on Pirkei Avot 2:11:1

R' Yehoshua says **Ayin Hara** means he's not happy in his lot, and looks at his fellow who's richer than him (feeling), When will he be rich like him, and he causes Ra (bad) to himself...

> רבי יהושע אומר **עין הרע**. פי' מי שאינו שמח בחלקו ועויין את חברו העשיר ממנו מתי יעשר עושר גדול כמוהו והוא גורם רע לעצמו. ולחברו כאשר אמרו חכמי הטבע....גם בקרבו ישרף אחר שמתאוה לדברים שאין יכולת מצוי בידו לעשות המחשבה ההיא מקלקלת גופו כי יתקצר רוחו ומציאתו מן העולם וזהו **עין הרע** שאמר ר' יהושע וראי' לזה הפי' על שאמר בכאן **עין הרע** בלשון זכר שזהו העויין ברע...ולמעלה אמר עין רעה שפי' על מדת הכילות שלא כדברי מקצת המפרשים ויצר הרע ושנאת הבריות כמשמען מוציאין את האדם מן העולם:

Midrash Tehillim 53:1

What is BLI'AL? it's Ayin haRa. Thus he says, "Lest there be a harsh thing on your heart BLI'AL."

> מהו בליעל זה **עין הרע**. וכן הוא אומר פן יהיה דבר עם לבבך בליעל. אמרה לו אדוני דוד לא היה לך ללמוד משמו נבל שמו ונבלה עמו. א"ר סימון הוא נבל הוא לבן הן הן האותיות. מה לבן היה רמאי כך נבל היה רמאי.

Midrash Tanchuma, Metzora 4:1

About Ayin haRa, said Rabbi Yitzchak, When a man's eye is evil toward lending out his items, a man comes and says to him, Lend me your scythe, lend me your axe, or whatever tool.  And he replies, Cursed is whoever has a scythe...

> ועל **עין הרע**. אמר רבי יצחק, כיון שעיניו של אדם רעה להשאיל חפציו, אדם הולך ואמר ליה, השאילני מגלך, השאילני קרדומך, או כל כלי חפץ. והוא אומר, ארור הוא מי שיש לו מגל או

Rashi on Exodus 30:12:2

Because quantity, Ayin haRa has power over it...

> שֶׁהַמִּנְיָן שׁוֹלֵט בּוֹ **עַיִן הָרָע**, וְהַדֶּבֶר בָּא עֲלֵיהֶם, כְּמוֹ שֶׁמָּצִינוּ בִימֵי דָּוִד :

Shulchan Arukh, Even HaEzer 62:3

...(Rema) But some say we shouldn't say the brachah for two grooms at once due to Ayin haRa..

> אם יש שני חתנים יחד מברכים ברכת חתנים אחת לשניהם: הגה ואפי' לא היו החתנים ביחד אלא שהיה דעתו על שניהם כמו שנתבאר בי"ד סי' רס"ה לענין מילה וי"א דאין לברך לב' חתנים ביחד משום **עין הרע** וכן נוהגין לעשות לכל

Midrash Tehillim 80:6

...Fish in the river, Ayin haRa has no power over them, as it says, "Let them multiply (w'yiDGu larov)"...

> מה דגים שביאור אין **עין הרע** שולטת בהן שנאמר וידגו לרוב. כך ישראל. ואם לאו מיער. מן חזירתא דחורשא. כיוצא בדבר אתה אומר משא מדבר ים. אם ים למה מדבר ואם מדבר למה ים.

---

Now, Rabbi Nachman of Breslev will actually not only give some segulot against Ayin haRa, but also trace its root (RA AIN = 400), in gematria equivalence, to Esau's 400 men, r"l:

Sichot Haran #242

The matter of Ayin haRa is: Because there's a real power in vision, for the power of looking goes out to his fellow and harms him, and when his eye is evil,
because vision is real power as the force of vision goes and entangles (*poge'a*) with the viewed object, so when his eye is evil it really harms by its looking, as mentioned.  Therefore a Niddah when she looks in a mirror there will be found an impression of blood there, as brought (in the books).  Now know, the Segular for Ayin haRa is the fin of a fish, to make it smoke.  The proof is SNPIR (400) is gematria R'A 'AIN (270+130)

> שיחות הר"ן - אות רמב
>
> אָמַר: עִנְיַן **עַיִן הָרָע** הוּא כִּי יֵשׁ כּחַ מַמָּשׁ בְּהָרְאִיָּה
> כִּי כּחַ הָרְאוּת הוֹלֵךְ לַחֲבֵרוֹ וּמַזִּיקוֹ כְּשֶׁעֵינוֹ רָעָה כִּי הָרְאִיָּה הִיא כּחַ מַמָּשׁ שֶׁהוֹלֵךְ כּחַ הָרְאוּת וּפוֹגֵעַ  בְּהַדָּבָר הַנִּרְאֶה וּכְשֶׁעֵינוֹ רָעָה מַזִּיק בִּרְאִיָּתוֹ מַמָּשׁ כַּנַּ"ל
> וְעַל כֵּן נִדָּה כְּשֶׁתִּסְתַּכֵּל בַּמַּרְאָה יִמָּצֵא שָׁם רשֶׁם דָּם כַּמּוּבָא
> וְדַע שֶׁסְּגֻלָּה לְעַיִן הָרָע סְנַפִּיר שֶׁל דָּג לְעַשֵּׁן בוֹ
> וְסִימָן סְנַפִּיר בְּגִימַטְרִיָּא רַע עַיִן

What's more mesugal is SNPIR of a fish called Shlayyin, which sounds like "Shel Ayin."  Also I heard in his name, his memory is blessed, a different wording:
Hang that fin on that man or child who sometimes has Ayin haRa.  Hang that fin on him and he'll be saved, as mentioned.

> וּבְיוֹתֵר מְסֻגָּל סְנַפִּיר שֶׁל מִן דָּגִים שֶׁקּוֹרִין אוֹתוֹ שְׁלְעַיֶין לָשׁוֹן נוֹפֵל עַל לָשׁוֹן, שֶׁל עַיִן
> עוֹד שָׁמַעְתִּי בִּשְׁמוֹ זִכְרוֹנוֹ לִבְרָכָה, נסַּח אַחֵר
> לִתְלוֹת הַסְּנַפִּיר הַנַּ"ל עַל הָאָדָם אוֹ תִּינוֹק שֶׁמֻּרְגָּל שֶׁיִּהְיֶה לוֹ לִפְעָמִים עַיִן הָרָע, יִתְלוּ עָלָיו סְנַפִּיר הַנַּ"ל וְיִנָּצֵל כַּנַּ"ל

Now he also told me more at that time.  He said Ayin haRa is drawn from the 400 men going with Esau to wage war with Yaakob, as it's written, "And four hundred men with him," and it's commented (in the Zohar etc.) that they came to cast Ayin haRa, God save us, on Yaakob's camp.  And SNPIR is 400, numerical to RA AIN, as we've related above.  So all this is against these 400 men of Esau, from whom Ayin haRa derives as mentioned.  Therefore SNPIR delivers from this, as mentioned. And he made consideration of several more things that add up to 400, that pertain to this matter.

> וְסִפֵּר לִי עוֹד שֶׁאָז אָמַר שֶׁעַיִן הָרָע נִמְשָׁךְ מֵהָאַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת אִישׁ שֶׁהָלְכוּ עִם עֵשָׂו לְהִלָּחֵם עִם יַעֲקב
> כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתוּב "וְאַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת אִישׁ עִמּוֹ"
> וְאִיתָא שֶׁהָלְכוּ לְהָטִיל עַיִן רָעָה חַס וְשָׁלוֹם, בַּמַּחֲנֶה שֶׁל יַעֲקב
> וּסְנַפִּיר הוּא מִסְפַּר אַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת שֶׁהוּא מִסְפַּר רַע עַיִן בִּמְכֻוָּן כַּנַּ"ל
> וְכָל זֶה הוּא כְּנֶגֶד הָאַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת אִישׁ שֶׁל עֵשָׂו הַנַּ"ל
> שֶׁמֵּהֶם נִמְשָׁךְ הָרַע עַיִן כַּנַּ"ל
> וְעַל כֵּן סְנַפִּיר מַצִּיל מִזֶּה כַּנַּ"ל
> וְעוֹד חָשַׁב אָז כַּמָּה דְבָרִים שֶׁעוֹלִים אַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת שֶׁהֵם שַׁיָּכִים לְעִנְיָן זֶה